# Помогите определить ошибку

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Есть свой адаптер

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Day> days;
private ArrayList<Day> realdays;

public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Day> days) {
    this.context = context;
    this.days = new ArrayList<Day>();
    this.days.addAll(days);
    this.realdays = new ArrayList<Day>();
    this.realdays.addAll(days);
}


@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return days.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<Schedule> topics = days.get(groupPosition).getTopics();
    return topics.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return days.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<Schedule> topics = days.get(groupPosition).getTopics();
    return days.get(childPosition);

}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Day day = (Day) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
    }
    TextView heading = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
    heading.setText(day.getDay());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Schedule topics = (Schedule)getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
    }
   TextView code = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
    TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView population = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.population);
    TextView abra = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.abra);
    TextView ka = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.kadabra);
    code.setText(topics.getPrepod());
    name.setText(topics.getName());
    population.setText(topics.getKon_p());
    abra.setText(topics.getNach_p());
    ka.setText(topics.getPlace());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

**Ругается на строку:**

`Schedule topics = (Schedule)getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);`

**Ошибка:**

`com.mobdev.testttt.Day cannot be cast to com.mobdev.testttt.Schedule
                      at com.mobdev.testttt.MyListAdapter.getChildView`

**Класс Day:**

```
public class Day {

private String day;
private ArrayList<Schedule> topics = new ArrayList<Schedule>();

public String getDay() {
    return day;
}

public ArrayList<Schedule> getTopics() {
    return topics;
}

public void setDay(String day) {
    this.day = day;
}

public void setTopics(ArrayList<Schedule> topics) {
    this.topics = topics;
}

public Day(String day, ArrayList<Schedule> topics) {
    super();
    this.day = day;
    this.topics = topics;
}
```

}

**Класс Shedule:**

```
public class Schedule {


private String para = "";
private String prepod = "";
private String place = "";
private String nach_p = "";
private String kon_p = "";
private String name = "";

public String getPara() {
    return para;
}

public String getPrepod() {
    return prepod;
}

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}

public String getNach_p() {
    return nach_p;
}

public String getKon_p() {
    return kon_p;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setPara(String para) {
    this.para = para;
}

public void setPrepod(String prepod) {
    this.prepod = prepod;
}

public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}

public void setNach_p(String nach_p) {
    this.nach_p = nach_p;
}

public void setKon_p(String kon_p) {
    this.kon_p = kon_p;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Schedule(String para, String prepod, String place, String nach_p, String kon_p , String name) {
    super();
    this.para = para;
    this.prepod = prepod;
    this.place = place;
    this.nach_p = nach_p;
    this.kon_p = kon_p;
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените Object на Schedule.

А именно, в строке:

```
@Override
public Object getChild(...
```

сделайте:

```
@Override
public Schedule getChild(...
```

Comment: Ошибка была чуть ниже,
    return days.get(childPosition);    надо было заменить на topics.get(childPosition);

Comment: ну, тем более )